# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _sre.SRE_Pattern found

Tags: python, regex

```
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)

oo = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'OpenOutcrier',count=10)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('morning.xlsx')
am_sheet = wb.active

for x in oo:
    tweettxt = x.text
    link2remove = 'http\w+'
    relink = re.compile(link2remove)
    if relink in tweettxt:
        tweettxt = tweettxt.replace(relink, '')
    print x.created_at, tweettxt
    am_sheet['%s' % ("H" + str(v))].value = tweettxt
    v += 1
    time.sleep(.1)

time.sleep(1)

wb.save('morning.xlsx')
```

I'm getting the error:

```
File "C:/Python27/Pyjects/am/morning.py", line 239, in <module>

    if relink in tweettxt:

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _sre.SRE_Pattern found
```

Having trouble getting this to work.. any help would be greatly appreciated. Assuming it's something i'm doing wrong with re.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), the syntax for regular expressions is:

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
```

So you want:

```
relink = re.compile(link2remove)
if relink.match(tweettxt):
```

Or, to replace the pattern found:

```
tweettxt = re.sub(link2remove, '', tweettxt)
```

Comment: Do you want me to detail something to accept the answer?